# Does jQuery offer an alternative to traditional timer - image swapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jQuery beginner and I've stumbled upon a situation where with traditional JavaScript, I would use a timer and swap images to produce an animated effect.

Does jQuery offer any alternative to the traditional JavaScript timer and image-swap animation effect?

(I have around 5 images that I would like to swap every quarter of a second or so)

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> Set a timer to delay execution of
>   subsequent items in the queue.

use it together with the [jQuery.queue](http://Show%20the%20queue%20of%20functions%20to%20be%20executed%20on%20the%20matched%20elements.)

> Show the queue of functions to be
>   executed on the matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping images, you can have them all loaded, but set CSS property "display: none" on all of them, except the one you want to show, for which you would set "display: block".

Another common way of displaying an image is using CSS background-image property, and altering its offset.  Historically this has been faster in many browsers than using a set of normal  elements!